To fit or not to fit: choosing between a model vs the average
I am writing mass spec data reduction software in which I am trying to model the exponential equations:
$$y = a \exp(-pt) + b$$
and
$$y = a \left(1 - \exp(-pt)\right) + y_0$$
where:

$t$ is the independent variable, time in seconds
$y$ is the dependent variable, intensity of gas in amperes
$a$, $b$, $p$, and $y_0$ are fitted parameters
$y_0$ is the desired "theoretical" intensity at $t=0$, or the intensity that we would have measured had the gas not needed to equilibrate in the vacuum chamber

The goal of this curve fitting is, therefore, to determine $y_0$ at $t=0$.
Given a dataset $t,y$, my program must first choose whether equation 1, 2, or a bulk average is appropriate. It does this by:

Fitting a linear model to the equation to determine the slope:
1a. If negative, the first equation $y=a\exp(-pt)+b$ is used
1b. If positive, the second equation $y=a\left(1-exp(-pt)\right)+y_0$

Calculating the Bayesian Information Criteria (BIC) for the given model and the bulk average:


$$\text{RSS} = \sum^{n}_{i=1}(y - y_\text{model})^2$$
$$\text{BIC} = k \ln\left(n\right) - n \ln{\left(\frac{\text{RSS}}{n}\right)}$$
where:

$\text{RSS}$ is the residual sum of squares
$\text{LL}$ is the log likelihood
$n$ is the number of measurements
$k$ is the number of parameters in the model

The approach with the lower $\text{BIC}$ is chosen to represent the data.
I have also tried the Aikake Information Criteria:
$$\text{AIC} = n \ln\frac{\text{RSS}}{n} + 2k$$
The BIC/AIC approach works very well in the vast majority of cases:

3 amu model BIC: -68.22736683860967 avg BIC: -19.07777539833865
3 amu y: [1.31675355e-09 1.31523499e-09 1.31489589e-09 1.31337669e-09 1.31298631e-09 1.31210217e-09 1.31155837e-09 1.31138789e-09 1.31036280e-09 1.30972014e-09 1.30984371e-09 1.30886948e-09]
3 amu y_err: [5.79372470e-12 5.78704303e-12 5.78555099e-12 5.77886648e-12 5.77714882e-12 5.77325860e-12 5.77086590e-12 5.77011580e-12 5.76560536e-12 5.76277768e-12 5.76332140e-12 5.75903479e-12]
3 amu t: [ 5.301 11.001 16.505 22.213 27.822 33.535 39.036 44.75  50.37  55.981 61.593 67.293]

4 amu model BIC: 8.34832953838457 avg BIC: 3.8746981950665136
4 amu y: [3.4737864e-12 3.4929198e-12 3.4690358e-12 3.4818411e-12 3.4736796e-12 3.5150694e-12 3.4830816e-12 3.4909808e-12 3.4908325e-12 3.4519882e-12 3.4877669e-12 3.5087559e-12]
4 amu y_err: [1.54148438e-14 1.54983236e-14 1.53941179e-14 1.54499858e-14 1.54143778e-14 1.55949727e-14 1.54553981e-14 1.54898633e-14 1.54892162e-14 1.53197467e-14 1.54758405e-14 1.55674229e-14]
4 amu t: [ 8.373 14.073 19.577 25.285 30.894 36.607 42.108 47.822 53.442 59.053 64.665 70.365]

however, there are also a large number of cases in which the BIC fails to fit the appropriate model even when the data appear ideal for it:

2 amu model AIC: 13.19702142961208 avg AIC: 9.197021335753153
2 amu y: [2.03507855e-09 2.03880799e-09 2.04374889e-09 2.04683769e-09 2.05260631e-09 2.05702917e-09 2.05790037e-09 2.06348189e-09 2.06594480e-09 2.06867414e-09 2.06907371e-09 2.07370048e-09]
2 amu y_err: [8.95448798e-12 8.97089752e-12 8.99263748e-12 9.00622816e-12 9.03161011e-12 9.05107069e-12 9.05490399e-12 9.07946268e-12 9.09029945e-12 9.10230856e-12 9.10406668e-12 9.12442448e-12]
2 amu t: [ 4.213  9.913 15.417 21.125 26.734 32.447 37.948 43.662 49.282 54.893 60.505 66.205]


2 amu model BIC: -12.687733687282623 avg BIC: -17.657546986858623
2 amu popt: [ -0.08864771 -12.73314558   2.29857579]
2 amu y: [2.16485748e-09 2.17965618e-09 2.19031464e-09 2.19841876e-09 2.20420420e-09 2.21237209e-09 2.21972994e-09 2.22112832e-09 2.22682700e-09 2.23348368e-09 2.23622192e-09 2.23740880e-09]
2 amu y_err: [9.52551529e-12 9.59062954e-12 9.63752677e-12 9.67318488e-12 9.69864083e-12 9.73457953e-12 9.76695411e-12 9.77310694e-12 9.79818114e-12 9.82747054e-12 9.83951880e-12 9.84474108e-12]
2 amu t: [ 3.323  9.036 14.849 20.262 25.866 31.568 37.17  42.772 48.392 54.096 59.698 65.316]

These last two models are just wrong: they are nearly ideal for the given equation $y=a(1-exp(-pt))+y_0$ and yet the bulk average yields a lower BIC or AIC by ~5. I therefore consider this result 'incorrect' given the trend.
How can I either 'fix' the BIC/AIC or find another means of determining whether the model or average is more appropriate for a given dataset?

$$y = a \exp(-pt) + b= a' \left(1 - \exp(-pt)\right) + y_0$$
$$a'=-a\quad;\quad y_0=a+b$$

Not an answer. But perhaps you benefit from having a peek at my Bayesian tutorial. You can read most of it online under "Read Sample."
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0BTNVFR65

While not a direct solution to the proposed problem (improve the AIC or BIC or find a different approach), it turns out that the AIC was 'failing' due to poor initial guesses supplied to the curve fitting algorithm. I have provided initial guesses to the exponential function based on this comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/658278/411984
Specifically, this is:

These equations are the work of @JJacquelin.
Providing these initial guesses to the curve fitting routine resolves the issue as presented.
